# How to perform integration tests with multiple steps

Tags: testing, integration-testing, assert

I've read a lot of questions about multiple asserts in tests. Some are against it and some think it's OK. But I'm starting to wonder how I should do it with longer tests that have many steps.

For example this test with an Android device:

1. Start wifi
2. Install app
3. Uninstall app
4. Stop wifi

*run test a couple of times*

As I want to run it multiple times and always in this order it has to be a single test(?). So then I'm forced to do four asserts on the way:

1. Check that wifi is on.
2. Check that the app got installed.
3. Check that the app got uninstalled.
4. Check that wifi is off.

*test is OK*

Is this wrong or ugly? I don't see how I could get away from it without splitting up the test and as I see it as a single test case it also seems wrong.

Comment: What user scenario does your test test? I'm trying to understand which of your assertions test that something happened that mattered to the user and which are just making sure that the test is doing what you think it is.

Comment: The essential part here is the install and the uninstall. But the wifi need to be on for the installation to work. So now when I think about it I guess the on/off of wifi could be in a setup/teardown.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the description: yes, this is wrong because of this part

> always in this order

A good unit test is isolated (not dependent on other tests) and its results are not dependent on a particular order of execution. This is important because many frameworks simply have no guarantee to the order of execution.

I think you can split that test up in multiple tests. Keep in mind that in order to test something you might have to change the state prior to it (which is what you do with starting/stopping WIFI) so this is something hard to overcome.

This could be your layout of tests:

```
StartWifi
StopWifi
InstallApp_WithWifiStarted_InstallsSuccesfully
InstallApp_WithoutWifiStarted_AbortsInstallation
```

and continue like this for uninstall (I'm not sure what the requirements for that are).

With these tests you will now have knowledge of the following:

- The wifi service can be started
- The wifi service can be stopped
- Installing the app with wifi works
- Installing the app without wifi doesn't work

Whereas with your single test you could only deduce from a failure that something went wrong throughout the line but it's unclear where. The problem could have been located at

- Starting wifi
- Installing app
- Uninstalling app
- Stopping wifi

With separate, smaller tests you can rule out the ones that aren't applicable because they work themselves.

[At this point I notice you changed the tag from unit-testing to integration-testing]

It's important to note though that what you do isn't bad per sé: larger units are good to test as well although, as you indicate yourself, this is where you're getting close to integration testing.

It's important that you use unit-testing and integration-testing as a complementary testing method: by having these smaller unit tests and your bigger integration test, you can verify that the smaller parts work and that the combination of them works.

---

**Conclusion**: yes, having several asserts in your test is okay but make sure you also have smaller tests to test the independent units.

Comment: Thanks for the god answer. Yeah I'm sorry for the unit-test tag, it should not really have been there as it is more of a integration test.   But it seems like it may be okay to use more than one assert in longer tests like this then.

Comment: Yes, a test has to assert against the things that it tests and nothing else. If the test tests multiple aspects then you have to, by definition, assert multiple steps. The same can go for smaller things: for example a simple `GetUserById` method can have asserts to check if the response is not `null` and whether the user's id, name, address and age are correct. That's multiple asserts but you still only assert one thing: whether the returned object is the way you expect it to be.

Comment: @user1776562 There is a school of thought that says you should have true unit tests & integration tests but no "hybrids": http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine to use multiple asserts in a single test. Your test is an integration test and it looks like an acceptance test, and it is normal for those (which exercise a big part of the system) to have many assertions. There should only be one *block* of assertions, however.

To illustrate that, here are the four tests I think you need to test the functionality you're testing (considering only happy paths):

- Test that the wifi can be turned on.

  - Turn the wifi on.
  - Assert that the wifi is on.
  - Turn the wifi off.
- Test that the wifi can be turned off:

  - Turn the wifi on.
  - Turn the wifi off.
  - Assert that the wifi is off.
- Test that the application can be installed:

  - Turn the wifi on.
  - Install the application
  - Assert that the application is installed.
  - Turn the wifi off.
  - Uninstall the application (if you need to do that to clean up).
- Test that the application can be uninstalled:

  - Turn the wifi on.
  - Install the application.
  - Uninstall the application.
  - Assert that the application is uninstalled.
  - Turn the wifi off.

Each test tests only one action. It might take multiple language-level assertions to test that that action did everything it was supposed to; that's fine. The point is that there's only one *block* of assertions, and it's at the end of the test (not counting cleanup steps). Tests that need setup code don't need to assert anything about whether that setup code succeeded; that was already done in another test. Likewise, actions that are used in cleanup steps (the steps which follow the assertions) are tested in one place and don't need to be tested again when they're used for cleanup. Each action is tested in one place. The result is that you only need to read one test to find out how a piece of functionality should behave, and you're more likely to need to change only one test if the way that functionality should behave changes.